# Outlier: How do I tag an outlier in a dataset in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I'm trying to extract outliers from my dataset and tag them accordingly.

Sample Data

```
     Doctor Name    Hospital Assigned         Region    Claims   Illness Claimed
1    Albert         Some hospital Center      R-1       20       Sepsis
2    Simon          Another hospital Center   R-2       21       Pneumonia
3    Alvin          ...                       ...       ...       ...
4    Robert
5    Benedict
6    Cruz
```

So I'm trying to group every `Doctor` that `Claimed` a certain `Illness` in a certain `Region` and trying to find outliers among them.

```
Doctor Name    Hospital Assigned         Region    Claims   Illness Claimed is_outlier
1    Albert    Some hospital Center      R-1       20       Sepsis         1
2    Simon     Another hospital Center   R-2       21       Pneumonia      0
3    Alvin       ...                       ...       ...       ...
4    Robert
5    Benedict
6    Cruz
```

I can do this in Power BI. But I can't seem to do it in R. I'm guessing that `group_by()` function of `dplyr` is involved. But I'm not sure.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: sample]

Algo goes like:

```
Read data
Group data by Illness
    Group by Region
    get IQR based on Claims Count
    if claims count > than (Q3 + 1.5) * IQR
        then tag it as outlier = 1
    else
        not an outlier = 0
Export data
```

I have done this before but this code loops through each Illnesses and applies Linear Regression for each. Is this anywhere near to what I'm trying to achieve?

```
# Loop through the dataframe and apply model
Ind <- sapply(split(df, list(df$Region,df$Illness_Code)), function(x)nrow(x)>1)

out <- lapply(
        split(df, list(df$Region, df$Illness_Code))[Ind],
         function(c){
          m <- lm(formula = COUNT ~ YEAR, data = c)
          coef(m)
         })
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use *group_by* + *boxplot_stats*. The first will do all combinations of groups and the second will return the outliers values:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(doc = sample(x = letters[1:3], size = 1000, replace = T), 
                 illness = sample(x = LETTERS[1:3], size = 1000, replace = T),
                 claims = rpois(n = 1000, lambda = 10))

df %>%
  group_by(doc, illness) %>%
  mutate(ind_out = if_else(claims %in% boxplot.stats(claims)$out, 1, 0))

# A tibble: 1,000 x 4
# Groups:   doc, illness [9]
   doc   illness claims ind_out
   <fct> <fct>    <int>   <dbl>
 1 c     A            8       0
 2 c     A           13       0
 3 b     C           18       0
 4 b     C            8       0
 5 b     C            8       0
 6 b     B           12       0
 7 a     C           10       0
 8 b     C            9       0
 9 a     B           15       0
10 c     B            8       0
# … with 990 more rows
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I have almost 2gb of .csv file. So this might take some time. I'll give you an update.